# Writing Category Instance for custom Lens

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

I have been reading this [article](http://www.haskellforall.com/2012/01/haskell-for-mainstream-programmers_28.html) for understanding Lenses. I know this is different from
Edward Knett's lens package, but nonetheless it's useful for fundamentals.

So, A Lens is defined like this:

```
type Lens a b = (a -> b, b -> a -> a)
```

It has been mentioned that Lenses form a category and I have been
trying out to create an instance for `Category` typeclass. For a start, I
wrote the type definition for the functions:

```
(.) :: Lens y z -> Lens x y -> Lens x z
id :: Lens x x
```

And after this, I just stare it for all day. What exactly is the
thought process for writing it's definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this [article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tel/lenses-from-scratch) (Lenses from Scratch on fpcomplete by Joseph Abrahamson) to be very good, it starts from the same representation of lenses you started with, defines composition for it and continues along the path to a representation more similar to [lens](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens)

EDIT: I find type holes to be excellent when doing this kind of things:

```
(<.>):: Lens y z -> Lens x y -> Lens x z
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (_,_)
```

So now we have 2 holes, the first in the tuple says (output cleaned):

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: x -> z
...
Relevant bindings include
  setB :: y -> x -> x
  getB :: x -> y
  setA :: z -> y -> y
  getA :: y -> z
  (<.>) :: Lens y z -> Lens x y -> Lens x z
```

Looking hard at the bindings, we already have what we need! `getB :: x -> y` and `getA :: y -> z` together with function composition `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`

So we happily insert this:

```
(<.>):: Lens y z -> Lens x y -> Lens x z
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (getA . getB, _)
```

And continue with the second type hole, which says:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: z -> x -> x
Relevant bindings include
  setB :: y -> x -> x
  getB :: x -> y
  setA :: z -> y -> y
  getA :: y -> z
```

The most similar thing we have is `setA :: z -> y -> y`, we start by inserting a lambda, capturing the arguments:

```
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (getA . getB, \z x -> _)
```

changing your type hole to:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: x
Relevant bindings include
  x :: x
  z :: z
  setB :: y -> x -> x
  getB :: x -> y
  setA :: z -> y -> y
  getA :: y -> z
```

we could insert `x` which type checks, but does not give us what we want (nothing happens when setting).  The only other binding that could give us an `x` is `setB`, so we insert that:

```
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (getA . getB, \z x -> setB _ _)
```

Our first type hole says:

```
Found hole ‘_’ with type: y
Relevant bindings include
  x :: x
  z :: z
  setB :: y -> x -> x
  getB :: x -> y
  setA :: z -> y -> y
  getA :: y -> z
```

So we need an y, looking at what is in scope, `getB` can give us a `y` if we give it a `x`, which we happen to have, but this would lead us to a useless lens doing nothing again.  The alternative is to use `setA`:

```
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (getA . getB, \z x -> setB (setA _ _) _)
```

(Speeding things a little up from here on)
Again the first hole wants something of type `z` which he happen to have as an argument to our lambda:

```
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (getA . getB, \z x -> setB (setA z _) _)
```

To fill the first type hole of type `y` we can use `getB :: x -> y` giving it the argument of our lambda:

```
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (getA . getB, \z x -> setB (setA z (getB x)) _)
```

Which leaves us with one remaining type hole, which can trivially be replaced by `x`, leading to the final definition:

```
(<.>):: Lens y z -> Lens x y -> Lens x z
(getA,setA) <.> (getB,setB) = (getA . getB, \z x -> setB (setA z (getB x)) x)
```

You can try to define `id` for yourself, using type holes and hoogle if necessary

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still interested to know how to define those functions.

Comment: Thanks, type holes seems quite awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(.) :: Lens y z -> Lens x y -> Lens x z
(getZfromY , setZinY) . (getYfromX , setYinX) = (getZfromX , setZinX)
             where getZfromX someX = ...
                   setZinX someZ someX = ...
```

The idea is: combine the two getters to make the new getter, and combine the two setters to make a new setter.

For the identity, think about:

```
id :: Lens x x
id = (getXfromX , setXinX)
    where getXfromX someX = ...
          setXinX newX oldX = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a fairly straighforward process. But also need to check that you get a category - this requires equational reasoning - because, for example, there is at least one more way to implement the setter of `id` with type `x->x->x` - only one of those will make a category.

So, let's start with getting functions of the right type.

```
Lens y z -> Lens x y -> Lens x z ==
(y->z, z->y->y) -> (x->y, y->x->x) -> (x->z, z->x->x)
```

It seems clear how to get `x->z` from `x->y` and `y->z` - compose. Well, and you have ways to construct new `x` from old `x` and new `y`, and a way to get old `y` from old `x`, so if you can construct new `y` from `z` and old `y`, you are done.

```
(.) (yz, zyy) (xy, yxx) = (yz . xy, \z x -> yxx (zyy z (xy x)) x)
```

Similarly for id:

```
Lens x x ==
(x->x, x->x->x)
```

So

```
id = (id, const)
```

So far so good, the types check. Now let's check that we've got a category. There is one law:

```
f . id = f = id . f
```

Checking one way (a bit informal, so need to bear in mind that `.` and `id` refer to different things in `f . id` and `fg . id`):

```
f . id = (fg, fs) . (id, const) =
(fg . id, \z x -> const (fs z (id x)) x) =
(fg, \z x -> fs z (id x)) = (fg, fs)
```

Checking the other way:

```
id . f = (id, const) . (fg, fs) =
(id . fg, \z x -> fs (const z (fg x)) x) =
(fg, \z x -> fs z x) = (fg, fs)
```